# Sonar excluding my TS files

Tags: typescript, sonarqube

Here is my `sonar-project.properties`

```
sonar.sources=src/ts
sonar.exclusions=**/*.less
sonar.tests=__tests__/ts
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*.ts
sonar.ts.lcov.reportpath=./coverage/coverage.lcov
```

When I run this, I get

```
INFO: Excluded sources: 
INFO:   **/*.less
INFO:   **/*.ts
INFO: Included tests: 
INFO:   **/*.ts
INFO: 0 files indexed
INFO: 44 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
```

Why are my `**/*.ts` excluded?!

Comment: Have a look [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters). Maybe there are some Global analysis parameters defined.

Comment: @JeroenHeier if I remove `sonar.test.inclusions=**/*.ts` then the Excluded `**/*.ts` goes away, but so then I get no files found to be indexed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All files matching the `sonar.test.inclusions` pattern are automatically excluded from the sources.  To fix the configuration you need to change its value to `sonar.test.inclusions=__tests__/ts/**/*.ts`.